# Not Sure if Postgresql Cube Gist Index is working

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I'm trying to figure out if my GIST index on my cube column for my table is working for my nearest neighbors query (metric = Euclidean).  My cube values are 75 dimensional vectors.

Table:

```
\d+ reduced_features
                   Table "public.reduced_features"
  Column  |  Type  | Modifiers | Storage | Stats target | Description
----------+--------+-----------+---------+--------------+-------------
 id       | bigint | not null  | plain   |              |
 features | cube   | not null  | plain   |              |
Indexes:
    "reduced_features_id_idx" UNIQUE, btree (id)
    "reduced_features_features_idx" gist (features)
```

Here is my query:

```
explain analyze select id from reduced_features order by features  <-> (select features from reduced_features where id = 198990) limit 10;
```

Results:

```
QUERY PLAN
---------------
 Limit  (cost=8.58..18.53 rows=10 width=16) (actual time=0.821..35.987 rows=10 loops=1)
   InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
     ->  Index Scan using reduced_features_id_idx on reduced_features reduced_features_1  (cost=0.29..8.31 rows=1 width=608) (actual time=0.014..0.015 rows=1 loops=1)
           Index Cond: (id = 198990)
   ->  Index Scan using reduced_features_features_idx on reduced_features  (cost=0.28..36482.06 rows=36689 width=16) (actual time=0.819..35.984 rows=10 loops=1)
         Order By: (features <-> $0)
 Planning time: 0.117 ms
 Execution time: 36.232 ms
```

I have 36689 total records in my table. Is my index working?

Comment: Maybe drop the index, and explain analyze the query and compare the results?

Comment: I dropped the index and the explain showed Seq Scan.  So i guess it's working since above it shows Index Scan, but the query took about the same amount time.  Maybe my number of rows is too small for it to make a difference now.

Comment: Seems likely. Do you have a mechanism to generate enough realistic data to see how the query performs on larger data sets?